# HTML5 whole website to match screen resolution on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, html

I have a web app that I created using html5,jquery and css that contains,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pascal Pattern Scan Laser Photocoagulator</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<!-- ImageReady Styles (1462_Next_Treatment_Flat.psd) -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
```

As you can see it was sliced in photoshop so for each slice i have a css div class e.g.

```
 div.Table_01 {
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      width:1024px;
      height:768px;
```

}

When viewing on mobile devices the width matches the screen however the height is too big for mobile screens (user has to scroll down) how can i match the resolution. Similar to a responsive design?

Also do i need to set height as AUTO in the html part of the code or the css or both?

```
<div class="Table_01">
<div class="id1462-Next-Treatment-Flat-01">
    <img src="images/1462_Next_Treatment_Flat_01.jpg" width="1024" height="479" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Use mediaQueries for mobile layout

Comment: Set height as auto ; You dont need to give height explicitely.Height is determined by content inside DIV

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Media Queries in css. Please go through below mentioned link for specific implementations...

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/